# Why does $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(x!)^{1/x}\neq 1?$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function, factorial

Why does $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(x!)^{1/x}\neq 1?$

As far as I know, anything to the power of $0$ is $1$.

We have a factorial raised to $1/\infty=0$, but the limit is not $1$? I don't even know what the limit is. But it seems like infinity? Why is this?

[image]

Comment: Yes, anything raised to the power of zero is $1$; but $1/x$ isn't zero (yet), and the thing being raised to that power is growing too fast for the limit to be $1$.  The limit is $\infty$.

Comment: @mjqxxxx, I guess what you mean is $\log (x!)^{1/x}$ is asymptotically $\log x$.

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1967813/evaluate-lim-x-to-infty-x1-x?rq=1

Comment: you should think about Stirling formula.

Comment: For no $x$ do we have $x!^0$. .... The limit, if there is one, of $f(x)^{1/x}$ as $x\to \infty,$ can be anything. E.g with $f(x)=2^x$ or $f(x)=3^x.$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That doesn't follow: $1/x$ is not the same as $0$ even for very large values of $x$. Keep in mind that "the limit as $x$ goes to infinity" is not the same thing as "plug in infinity wherever you see $x$". It is about how the function is behaving for larger and larger $x$. No matter how large $x$ gets, $1/x$ is still positive and as such we can find a (possibly huge) real number $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^{1/x}$ is as big as we want. For example, you will agree that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (a^x)^{1/x} = a.$$

Combining this with the fact that $x! > a^x$ for any $a$ and sufficiently large $x$, it shouldn't be too surprising that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (x!)^{1/x} = \infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

Method (1). Prove the following: If $f(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$ then $G(n)=\frac {1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nf(j)\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty.$

With $f(x)=\ln x$ we have $G(n)=\ln (n!^{(1/n)}).$

Method (2). $\ln x$ is monotonic increasing. So for $n\geq 2$ we have $\ln n>\int_{n-1}^n \ln x\;dx  .$ So $$\ln n!=\sum_{j=2}^n \ln j>\sum_{j=2}^n\int_{j-1}^j\ln x\;dx=\int_1^n \ln x \;dx=n(\ln n)-n+1.$$ Therefore for n\geq 2 we have  $$\ln (n!^{(1/n)})=\frac {1}{n}\ln n!>\frac {1}{n}(n (\ln n)-n+1)=(\ln n)-1+\frac {1}{n}.$$

Answer (score 1):

A useful inequality is
$n! > (n/e)^n$.
This can be proved by induction
from
$(1+1/n)^n < e$.

From this
$(n!)^{1/n} > n/e$
and this last is unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

As Salahamam_ Fatima commented, think about Stirling approximation.

$$y=(x!)^{1/x}\implies \log(y)=\frac 1x \log(x!)$$ Now, using Stirling approximation $$\log(x!)=x (\log (x)-1)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log (2 \pi )+\log
   \left({x}\right)\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ $$\log(y)=(\log (x)-1)+\frac{\log (2 \pi )+\log \left({x}\right)}{2 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ and now,  $$y=e^{\log(y)}=\frac{x}{e}+\frac{\log (2 \pi )+\log \left({x}\right)}{2 e}+O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$